# Unable to execute SQL queries on remote server

Tags: sql-server-2008, jira

I am connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 instance (running on my local host) using the jtds driver and trying to execute basic query as follows.

```
select * from Test
```

However I get an SQLException as -

> java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [select * from Test]

Interestingly I can log in to the server and manually execute the same query without any problems.

I have also tried the following options

1. `select * from <DB name>.dbo.Test`
2. `select * from dbo.Test`
3. `select * from [Test]`

The user I am logging in has db admin rights for all the databases.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

connect to the db in your connection to the same database in which the table is.

Comment: Yes I am connecting the same database by providing the DB name in the connection string


jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/<DB Name>